# What is the function of the list of loop devices?

Tags: loop-device, kubuntu-netbook

A lot of strange loop devices appear in my Kubuntu OS.

[image]

```
 [translation:  
  Hard disk 107.4GB  
  Hard disk 487.0GB  
  Loop Device  
  Hard Disk 4.0GB  
  Loop Device  
  Loop Device  
  Loop Device  
  Loop Device  
  Victor Disk]
```

Can anybody tell me what it is? .

Answer (score 7):

The loop devices come from snap packages that you installed, one loop device for each snap package that is installed. If gnome-disk-utility package is installed, ISO images can be mounted as loop devices in Dolphin file manager's left pane under the *Devices* heading.

If you unmount the loop device of a snap package, the snap application will stop working until the next time you reboot or restart the computer, and then it will resume working normally. The right way to disable/enable a snap in the system is with the command `sudo snap disable <name-of-snap-package>` and enable a snap with `sudo snap enable <name-of-snap-package>`. The way to permanently delete a snap loop device is to uninstall the snap with the command `sudo snap remove <name-of-snap-package>`.

Comment: So, thank you very much for your answer. Then,  can i delete or how can I deletes this loops? Thank you.

Comment: @victorsnk I added my reply to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think that my problem is I can't understand well how works SNAP. I believed that you installed a program and then it works installed in the system. But really  this remains like a external unit.

Comment: @victorsnk Snap packages are different from other packages in Ubuntu Software because they are standalone packages that are usually bundled with their own dependencies (similar to programs for Windows). This makes snap packages larger than regular packages, but they are inert and self-contained with respect to the operating system's package management. If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.